# foldr resulting in stack overflow

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to generate primes using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm on an infinite list. I've heard that foldr will examine the list lazily, but every time I try to use the following algorithm I get a stack overflow exception:

```
getPrimes :: [Int]
getPrimes = foldr getNextPrime [2] [3,5..]
    where
        getNextPrime n primes
            | not $ isAnyDivisibleBy primes n = primes ++ [n]
            | otherwise = primes
        isAnyDivisibleBy primes n = any (\x -> isDivisibleBy n x) primes
        isDivisibleBy x y = x `mod` y == 0
```

example:

```
takeWhile (\x -> x < 10) getPrimes
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Somewhere the list is getting evaluated, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: That title can be read in two ways ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `foldr` is confusing you, so let's write it out with explicit recursion:

```
getPrimes :: [Int]
getPrimes = getPrimesUsing [3,5..]

getPrimesUsing :: [Int]->[Int]
getPrimesUsing [] = [2]
getPrimesUsing (n:primes)
  | not $ isAnyDivisibleBy primes n = primes ++ [n]
  | otherwise = primes
  where
    primes = getPrimesUsing primes
    isAnyDivisibleBy primes n = any (\x -> isDivisibleBy n x) primes
    isDivisibleBy x y = x `mod` y == 0
```

Can you see the trouble now?

An unrelated point: the algorithm you seem to be trying to implement here is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but rather a much less efficient algorithm called trial division.

Answer (score 2):

`foldr getNextPrime [2] [3, 5 .. ]` expands to:

```
(getNextPrime 3 (getNextPrime 5 (getNextPrime 7 ...
```

Since `getNextPrime` always needs to inspect its second argument, we just get a non-terminating chain of `getNextPrime` calls, and the initial `[2]` list is never used.

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` is defined as

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So when you plug in the arguments you would get

```
foldr getNextPrime [2] [3,5..]
    = getNextPrime 3 (foldr getNextPrime [2] [5,7..])
    = getNextPrime 3 (getNextPrime 5 (foldr getNextPrime [2] [7,9..])
    etc...
```

For this to lazily produce values (what you want when dealing with infinite lists) then `getNextPrime` needs to lazily produce values.  Looking at the definition of `getNextPrime`, `primes ++ [n]`, meaning you're appending a value onto the end of your `primes` list, but `primes` for `getNextPrime 3` is `getNextPrime 5 (foldr getNextPrime [2] [7,9..])`.  But then `primes` for `getNextPrime 5` is `getNextPrime 7 (foldr getNextPrime [2] [9,11..])`, etc, etc.  You never actually are able to produce a normal form value for `primes`, it's always a chain of computations that never return.

Another way to look at this is to look at this is to replace `getNextPrime` with an operator, let's call it `.:`

```
foldr (.:) [2] [3,5..9]
    = 3 .: (5 .: (7 .: (9 .: [2])))
```

(this is why it's called a right fold, the parens are nested to the right)

This works great for using `:` in `foldr`:

```
foldr (:) [2] [3,5..9]
    = 3 : (5 : (7 : (9 : [2])
```

because `:` just builds a new data structure, and the first element of this data structure can be inspected without calculating the rest of the structure.  But `.:` isn't so nice, it first needs to calculate `x1 = 9 .: [2]`, then `x2 = 7 .: x1`, then `x3 = 5 .: x2`, and finally `3 .: x3`.  For `[3,5..]` instead, you never can calculate the last call of `something .: [2]`, but haskell keeps trying to compute it and that blows the stack.